# Apply function slow in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>> df      
  A
0 [{k1:v1, k2:v2}, {k1:v3, k2:v4}]
1 [{k1:v5, k2:v6}, {k1:v7, k2:v8}, {k1:v9, k2:v10}]
```

that is column A is a list of dicts with same keys

and I want to extract the values corresponding to the first dict in those lists:

```
  K1 K2 A
0 v1 v2 ...
1 v5 v6 ...
```

my solution so far works but is particularly slow (> 1min for ~50K records):

```
def extract_first_dict(s):
    s['K1'] = s['A'][0]['k1']
    s['K2'] = s['A'][0]['k2']
    return s
df = df.apply(extract_first_dict, axis = 1)
```

Anybody could suggest a better, faster way to do this?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `concat`

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.A.str[0].tolist(), index=df.index), df], axis=1)

   k1  k2                                                  A
0  v1  v2  [{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, {'k1': 'v3', 'k2': ...
1  v5  v6  [{'k1': 'v5', 'k2': 'v6'}, {'k1': 'v7', 'k2': ...
```

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**

You should find `pd.Series.apply` more efficient than `pd.DataFrame.apply`, as you are using only one series as an input.

```
def extract_first(x):
    return list(x[0].values())

df['B'] = df['A'].apply(extract_first)
```

**Option 2**

You can also try using a list comprehension:

```
df['B'] = [list(x[0].values()) for x in df['A']]
```

In both the above cases, you can split into 2 columns via:

```
df[['C', 'D']] = df['B'].apply(pd.Series)
```

You should benchmark with your data to assess whether either of these options are fast enough for your use case.

**But really...**

Look upstream to get your data in a more usable format. `pandas` will offer no vectorised functionality on a series of dictionaries. You should consider using just a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

```
df.A.str[0].apply(pd.Series)

   k1  k2
0  v1  v2
1  v5  v6
```

with `join`

```
df.A.str[0].apply(pd.Series).join(df)

   k1  k2                                                  A
0  v1  v2  [{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, {'k1': 'v3', 'k2': ...
1  v5  v6  [{'k1': 'v5', 'k2': 'v6'}, {'k1': 'v7', 'k2': ...    ​
```

---

### Option 2

```
pd.DataFrame([t[0] for t in df.A], df.index)

   k1  k2
0  v1  v2
1  v5  v6
```

with `join`

```
pd.DataFrame([t[0] for t in df.A], df.index).join(df)

   k1  k2                                                  A
0  v1  v2  [{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, {'k1': 'v3', 'k2': ...
1  v5  v6  [{'k1': 'v5', 'k2': 'v6'}, {'k1': 'v7', 'k2': ...

​
```